# xAttribute: when to use explicit conversion?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

In my project, I have an xml element called `nwCounter`, which contains a number of elements called `Wire` and each of those elements has a unique attribute `UId` which is an integer number. Not all numbers have been used.

As I use linq-to-xml, I can search for the highest UId number in two ways:

```
Dim test1 As Integer = nwCounter.Descendants(networkNameSpace + "Wire").Max(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("UId").Value))
Dim test2 As Integer = nwCounter.Descendants(networkNameSpace + "Wire").Max(Function(x) x.Attribute("UId").Value)
```

The result of `test` is `124`, the result of `test2` is `99`. The first one being the correct one.

So my question is: should I always use explicit conversion? Or when is it okay to use the implicit conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this question did not generate a lot of traction, but a few weeks later, it dawned on me what the problem was:

The `Max` function always searches for the highest value, but it does not take information on the type. By default, it seems to assume the type is a string.

If you arrange all the attributes by alphabet, `99` becomes higher than `124`. The reason I did not see this earlier, was because I only used values between 10 and 99, so I didn't encounter this problem.